# Windows 7 driver service start

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel, driver

I'm trying to run a driver service on Windows 7. First my code installs the service, then it tries to run it. My problem is that StartService returns error code 2 - "The system cannot find the file specified.".

The driver and code are developed in Windows 10, debugged on 32bit win7 virtual machine. The driver is developed for windows 7 however.

Procmon showed pretty strange behavior in StartService - services.exe only queried HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\KMDFDriver2\ObjectName key, which doesn't exist. The path to .sys file is in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\KMDFDriver2\ImagePath. I suspect this might be the cause.

Can you please help?

```
SC_HANDLE InstallDriver(LPCWSTR driverName, LPCWSTR binaryPath)
{
    SC_HANDLE scmDBHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (scmDBHandle == NULL)
    {
        DBG_TRACE("InstallDriver", "could not open handle to SCM database");
        PrintError();
        return NULL;
    }
    SC_HANDLE svcHandle = CreateService(
        scmDBHandle,
        driverName,
        driverName,
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
        SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        binaryPath,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );
    if (svcHandle == NULL)
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        if (lastError == ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS)
        {
            DBG_TRACE("InstallDriver", "driver already installed");
            svcHandle = OpenService(scmDBHandle, driverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
            if (svcHandle == NULL)
            {
                DBG_TRACE("InstallDriver", "could not open handle to driver");
                PrintError();
                CloseServiceHandle(scmDBHandle);
                return NULL;
            }
            CloseServiceHandle(scmDBHandle);
            return svcHandle;
        }
        DBG_TRACE("InstallDriver", "could not create handle to driver");
        PrintError();
        return NULL;
    }
    DBG_TRACE("InstallDriver", "Function returning succesfuly");
    CloseServiceHandle(scmDBHandle);
    return svcHandle;
}

BOOL LoadDriver(SC_HANDLE svcHandle)
{
    //DebugBreak();
    if (StartService(svcHandle, 0, NULL) == 0)
    {   
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING)
        {
            DBG_TRACE("loadDriver", "driver already running");
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            DBG_TRACE("loadDriver", "driver failed loading");
            PrintError();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    DBG_TRACE("loadDriver", "driver loaded succesfuly");
    return TRUE;
}


int main() {
    SC_HANDLE driver = InstallDriver(L"KMDFDriver2", L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\KMDFDriver2.sys");
    LoadDriver(driver);
    CloseServiceHandle(driver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your driver installer compiled as x86 and running on x64 Windows, there might be this issues with Windows filesystem and registy redirection. Briefly - there are different directories for x86 environment placed in `%WINDIR%\SysWoW64\` and native x64 environment in `%WINDIR%\System32`. If your x86 installer tries to open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\KMDFDriver2.sys` file, it will get `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers\KMDFDriver2.sys` path. To avoid this, try to use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aa384187

If it is not helpful, check your `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` definition, Since you use `DBG_TRACE` that used `LPCSTR`, it is likely not defined. Unicode string will be valid ANSI string, but it will be truncated to first zero byte - and there will be only 1 char. So Windows can not reach driver named `"K"` with binary path named `"C"`

Comment: No, it is running on x86 Windows 7 in virtualbox.

Comment: Is `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` defined?